# Format as DD/MM/YYYY showing as D/M/YYYY

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am pulling data from a table row in Excel, and adding it into another table, using VBA. One of the fields I'm pulling across is a date field, formatted as DD/MM/YYYY in the source table. The code I'm using to transfer the data is

`.Range(5) = Format(offline.ListColumns(12).Range(i), "DD/MM/YYYY")`

But the data is appearing as D/M/YYYY. i.e. a date of 05/01/2020 is appearing as 5/1/2020.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What does `.Range(5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` do?

Comment: If you want the date to show in your desired format, you must format the target cell either as text, or as date with your desired format: `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: BigBen, nothing, it turns out! I was using it to try and format the date properly, but Ron is right - I needed to format the target cell instead.

Comment: `Range.NumberFormat` *is* what you would use to format the target cell... I'm not sure what your comment means. In any case, it sounds like the problem is resolved.